# How to find social media links in HTML with python using etree

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Some sites don't work with the Python package `html_to_etree` using `headers`. In the below example with Fox vs CNN, both sites have links to social media within the page. However, one works with `res.headers.get('content-type')`, and the other doesn't. Any idea how to use`res.body.get()` to find the social media links in the `www.heavybit.com` href links using the modified `.get`?

```
# !pip install 
# ! pip install extract_social_media 

import requests
from html_to_etree import parse_html_bytes
from extract_social_media import find_links_tree

res = requests.get('https://www.foxnews.com/')
# res = requests.get('https://www.cnn.com/')

tree = parse_html_bytes(res.content, res.headers.get('content-type'))

links = set(find_links_tree(tree))
links

# Fox
# {'https://twitter.com/foxnews',
#  'https://www.facebook.com/FoxNews',
#  'https://www.google.com/+FoxNews',
#  'https://www.instagram.com/foxnews',
#  'https://www.linkedin.com/company/fox-news-channel'}

# CNN
# {'https://plus.google.com/+cnn/posts'}
# Shouls include Twitter / FB / Insta
```

Comment: May be useful: https://github.com/fluquid/html-to-etree/blob/4c69a8900a2336d89dcb07e6b621078e4e294ebe/src/html_to_etree/__init__.py

Comment: HTML to Unicode "w3lib.encoding"

Comment: How you were able to install `html_to_etree` package?